# Access directive's controller function inside link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to access the directives controller functions in link? This returns error:
ReferenceError: getFormatedValue is not defined.

Saw some examples where one injects a seperate controller through require and is able to access the controller by injecting it, as seen below in my code, as the 4th param in the link function. However, i need this controller to be inside this directive.

```
.directive('testDirective', function () {
    link: function ($scope, element, attribute, controller) {

        attribute.$observe('numbers', function(value) { 
            controller.setNumbers(value);
        });

        attribute.$observe('decimals', function(decimals) { 
            decimals = decimals || defaultValue();
            decimals = (decimals.length > 2 ? decimals.slice(0, 2 - decimals.length) : decimals);
            $scope.decimals = controller.getFormatedValue(decimals, 'decimals');
        });

    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        this.setNumbers = function (numbers) {
            numbers = numbers || $scope.defaultValue();
            $scope.numbers = getFormatedValue(numbers, 'numbers');
        };

        this.getFormatedValue = function(value, kindofvalue){
            var maxDecimals = '2',
                    returnValue;

            if (kindofvalue === 'decimals'){
                returnValue = addzero(value, maxDecimals);
            }
            else if (kindofvalue === 'numbers'){
                    returnValue = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
            }
            return returnValue;
        };

        this.defaultValue = function() {
            return '0';
        };

        this.addzero = function(decimalValue , maxDecimals) {
            return decimalValue.length < maxDecimals ? $scope.addzero(decimalValue + '0', maxDecimals) : decimalValue;
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `require: 'testDirective'` to the directive definition, i.e.:

```
.directive('testDirective', function () {
    return {
        require: 'testDirective',
        link: function ($scope, element, attribute, controller) {
            ...
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Solved it. No need to add "require: 'testDirective'", but these lead me into figuring it out. The code actually works but there was a reference problem inside a function in the controller breaking it. function 'addzero' wasnt referenced through this. The feedback i received wasnt really clear so I thought I wasnt able to access the controller in the isolated scope.